# Bundled versions of rspec and cucumber gems in a new rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, bundler

I am experiencing a problem with the cucumber and rspec gems bundled in a rails app.

This is what my `Gemfile` looks like in a new Rails 3.2.11 application with RSpec support added:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

After running `bundle`, `Gemfile.lock` reports that `rspec 2.12.2` is being used (the latest version of the gem, as of this writing).

But I also want to use cucumber, so I run `bundle update` after modifying `Gemfile` like so:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
end
```

**To my surprise, the bundled rspec is now version `2.0.1`, definitely NOT cool.**

In fact, this was causing all kinds of errors when running specs, and it took me a while to figure out that they were old rspec errors, fixed long ago.

I can force bundler to use the latest gem:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.12.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
end
```

but I am unhappy, because I do not understand:

1. if I did something wrong to begin with
2. if the fix I applied is going to cause other problems down the road
3. if there was a way to predict this behavior

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/cucumber-rails.gemspec#L22, cucumber-rails depends on 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.10.1' (which means >= 2.10.1 and < 2.11). If any other upstream dependency depends on a version of rspec < 2.10.1 or >= 2.11, bundler should raise an error, so I can't understand how this happened.

As an aside, you should include rspec-rails in both the `:development` and `:test` groups (per https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#configure).

Comment: I am not on cucumber-rails/master, I am using the most recent gem, which is 1.3.0. Still, its gemspec says 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.7.0', so yeah, why doesn't bundler complain.

I have reproduced the problem with yet another new rails app, within a fresh rvm environment (mri 1.9.3-p327 and dedicated gemset), with both cucumber-rails and rspec-rails within a :test AND :development group. Bundler installs cucumber-rails 1.3.0 and rspec 2.0.1... Anything I could upload that might help? Thanks!